# Why do google backup and sync add the underscore at the end of the name of some folders?

Tags: google-backup-and-sync

Why do google backup and sync add the underscore at the end of the name of some folders?

that folder doesn't have that underscore in the drive

Answer (score 0):

it seems because that a single space is there on the drive side, that's why google backup and sync replace the space with underscore